# JSON deserialization of Datetime till milliseconds in c#

Tags: c#, datetime, json-deserialization

I wanted do deserialize a JSON string/object and the JSON object contains some date-time fields.

My function to deserialize JSON object is-

```
public static T ParseJSONToObject<T>(string entity)
{

  return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(entity, new    IsoDateTimeConverter{
            DateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fffffff"                              
        });

}
```

I wanted the date-time fields should convert till milliseconds and if there is no value in milliseconds then it should show zero's till 7 digits. Below is my JSON object-

```
[
  {"Key": "PendingDate", "Value": "2017-06-15T13:58:00"},
  {"Key": "OwnerId", "Value": "xyz"},
  {"Key": "ProductList", "Value": "0"},
  {"Key": "CreatedDate", "Value": "2017-06-16T09:11:21.678544"},
  {"Key": "ModifiedDate", "Value": "2017-06-16T09:11:21.678544"}
]
```

But when I am passing this object to my jSON parser function it's not returning the date-time values in my desired format.

But when I use below code to de-serialize a single json string it's giving correct output-

```
          var json = "{\"timestamp\":\"2017-06-15T13:58:00.000\"}";
          var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,     object>>(json);
          var r = ((DateTime)dict["timestamp"]).ToString("O");
```

And the output will be-

```
  2017-06-15T13:58:00.0000000
```

That is the output that I needed but I am not sure how I need to implement
this with my JSON parser function.

Comment: You have an array of dictionaries, not a single dictionary. Besides, the `DateTime` type has no format at all. It's a binary value like `int` and `double`. Your *code* though, converts the date to a *string*. What are you asking  after all this?

Comment: Post code that actually shows the problem. What you posted suggests you  confused string representations with some (non-existent) DateTime format. BTW ISO8601 is the default for JSON.NET. You don't need to specify it

Answer (score 0):

No need to specify DateTimeFormat because default format reads milliseconds. You will be losing milliseconds during object to DateTime conversion. Try parsing content into dynamic type instead of object type, to avoid conversions needed for compiler.

Update: removed foreach loop to display value.

```
  /// <summary>
  /// Specifies the settings on a <see cref="T:Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer" /> object.
  /// </summary>
  public class JsonSerializerSettings
  {
     ...
     internal const string DefaultDateFormatString = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.FFFFFFFK";
```

Sample code

```
   var data = "[{\"Key\": \"PendingDate\", \"Value\": \"2017-06-15T13:58:00\"},  {\"Key\": \"OwnerId\", \"Value\": \"xyz\"},  {\"Key\": \"ProductList\", \"Value\": \"0\"},  {\"Key\": \"CreatedDate\", \"Value\": \"2017-06-16T09:11:21.678544\"},  {\"Key\": \"ModifiedDate\", \"Value\": \"2017-06-16T09:11:21.678544\"}]";

   var deserilizedData = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OrderDetail[]>(data);

   var order = deserilizedData.ToDictionary(r => r.Key, r => r.Value);

   Console.WriteLine("PendingDate: " + order["PendingDate"].ToString("o"));
   Console.WriteLine("OwnerId: " + order["OwnerId"].ToString());
   Console.WriteLine("ProductList: " + order["ProductList"].ToString());
   Console.WriteLine("CreatedDate: " + order["CreatedDate"].ToString("o"));
   Console.WriteLine("ModifiedDate: " + order["ModifiedDate"].ToString("o"));
```

Output

```
PendingDate: 2017-06-15T13:58:00.0000000
OwnerId: xyz
ProductList: 0
CreatedDate: 2017-06-16T09:11:21.6785440
ModifiedDate: 2017-06-16T09:11:21.6785440
```

Entity to deserialize

```
public class OrderDetail
{
    public string Key { get; set; }

    public dynamic Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hi Kaushal...thanks for your reply but I don't want to use loop in this case. I need a direct solution without using any loop.

Comment: @user3848036 Loop is just to display value. What I meant to say is DeserializeObject will parse and preserve milliseconds. You might be loosing them while converting from object type. Please share code how you use parsed value. To validate it indeed preserve value, you can put breakpoint on returned value and cross check milliseconds property

Answer (score 0):

Try make that.

```
class Test
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

-

```
DateTime dtParse;

var deserializeJson = (from d in JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Test[]>(entity)
                       select new Test()
                       {
                             Key = d.Key,
                             Value = DateTime.TryParse(d.Value, out dtParse) == true ? Convert.ToDateTime(d.Value).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffff") : d.Value
                       }).ToList();
```

Comment: I simplified my answer and I believe this is you looking for.

Comment: @log thanks for your reply. But can you please suggest any way with "IsoDateTimeConverter", because I can't hard coded the property names that you did in your code. Because I have a global function that work for any object and any property name of Datetime type.

Comment: I really tried use `IsoDateTimeConverter`, but didn't make it, I founded the alternative solution, look and tell me what you think